# Heroku log says ReferenceError: PORT is not defined

Tags: mysql, heroku

I deployed my backend server to heroku and the build finished without any problems, but when I went to check the app, I got an application error. I checked the log to see what went wrong and I discovered this error

```
2021-04-17T18:50:16.876463+00:00 app[web.1]: app.listen(PORT, () => {
2021-04-17T18:50:16.876464+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-17T18:50:16.876464+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-17T18:50:16.876465+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: PORT is not defined
```

I then went to check on my backend server if I defined the PORT correctly and it was correct as shown here

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

So I went to the internet to see if someone had the same problem as me but unfortunately, I couldn't find any that was similar to mine so I don't know what is wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I managed to solve it. I removed the unnecessary postinstall from my package.json and it's now working all fine and dandy